# A compact set contained in an open set is contained in a rectangle contained in the open set?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

So I had this question: suppose $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $K\subset U$ (assume that $K$ is non-empty). Is it true that $K$ is contained in a disjoint union of finitely many closed rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contained in $U$?

I had to ask this question because there is a particular statement in Rudin's proof of the change of variables formula that I'm unable to verify the details of. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative if $K$ is a [connected subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space). More generally, a connected subset can't be covered by finitely many closed disjoint subsets $C_1, \dots, C_n$. If that would be the case, the union of the disjoint closed subsets $K \cap C_1, \dots, K \cap C_n$ would be equal to $K$. In contradiction with the definition of a connected subset.

If $K$ is not connected, then this may be possible, i.e. if $K$ is the union of two disjoint closed rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the [tube lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma):

If $K \subset X \times Y$ is compact and $K \subseteq N$ open then there are open $U \subseteq X$ and $V \subseteq Y$ such that $K \subseteq U \times V \subseteq N$.

An even more general fact for general products can be found as Wallace’s theorem in Engelking (chapter on compactness).

The above Wiki-link already sketches the proof for this two space version, which can be extended to finite products (as $\Bbb R^n$) by induction.